# HTTPS with Python 2.7 CGIHTTPServer

Tags: python, ssl, cgi-bin

I already have a web service running using Python 2.7 CGIHTTPServer.  It's great. It's lightweight. However, I now require it to work with HTTPS and a certificate that I have. There are very few instructions on how to do this. In fact there is only one article that I found for Python 2.7.

My question is simple and very narrow. **Given the instructions below, how do I launch it?**  I already have a python script that is transaction based.  You call it, it processes your request. It needs SSL.

https://blog.farville.com/15-line-python-https-cgi-server

This expects a directory structure:

```
/ssl_server.py
/localhost.pem
/html/index.html   html lives here, aka “root directory”
/html/cgi/         python scripts live here
```

Self Signed SSL cert made with openssl like this:

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout localhost.pem \
-out localhost.pem -days 3650 -nodes
```

ssl_server.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys
import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
import cgitb; cgitb.enable() ## This line enables CGI error reporting
import ssl
server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8443)
handler.cgi_directories = ["/cgi"]
os.chdir("html")
srvobj = server(server_address, handler)
srvobj.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (srvobj.socket, certfile="../localhost.pem", server_side=True)
# Force the use of a subprocess, rather than
# normal fork behavior since that doesn't work with ssl
handler.have_fork=False
srvobj.serve_forever()
```

**So what now?**  Again, keep in mind I have another python script that already successfully processes web requests.

Comment: I don't think it gets better if you ask [**exactly the same question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094381/using-ssl-with-python-cgihttpserver?noredirect=1#comment75230325_44094381) again but to state again: you launch it with `python ssl_server.py`. You access it with `https://localhost:8443`. And it does not matter if you have another script successfully running, as long as it does not use the same port.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich.  since my last question was put on hold, I was hoping to open up the question to other people who may have tried this and had problems.

Comment: One modification is that I am not doing this on localhost with a self-signed certificate. I am using a certificate from a CA.  I have a .key and .crt file which I put together in a .pem file according to instructions I found on stackoverflow.  Also, I can't test this with a browser since I have only a SSH terminial.  I'll find out how to test HTTPS locally from the command line.

Comment: Hey @SteffenUllrich, thank you!  I think you led me to the root cause here.  I tried to hit localhost using a curl command and by the looks of the error message, I don't think I have the CA server certificate required. Thank you very much for your patience and helping me thru this!

Comment: I actually had to install GoDaddy's root and/or intermediate certs (I installed all of them), then I had to switch the port to 443.  Works now like a charm.  @SteffenUllrich, I would like to thank you and I wish I can mark one of your comments as the answer or give you some points, but it doesn't look like you are lacking those.

Answer (score 1):

I added keyfile next to cert file, and executed `python ssl_server.py`, it worked

```
srvobj.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (srvobj.socket, certfile="/etc/letsencrypt/live/myowndomain.com/cert.pem", keyfile="/etc/letsencrypt/live/myowndomain.com/privkey.pem" server_side=True)
```